# Laravel 8 BadMethodCallException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, tinker

I am learning laravel 8, I keep getting this error

```
   BadMethodCallException 

  Call to undefined method App\Models\Question::factory()

  at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\laravels\qna\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:50
     46▕      * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     47▕      */
     48▕     protected static function throwBadMethodCallException($method)
     49▕     {
  ➜  50▕         throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
     51▕             'Call to undefined method %s::%s()', static::class, $method
     52▕         ));
     53▕     }
     54▕ }

  • Bad Method Call: Did you mean App\Models\Question::toArray() ?

  1   C:\Users\USER\Desktop\laravels\qna\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:36
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::throwBadMethodCallException("factory")

  2   C:\Users\USER\Desktop\laravels\qna\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:1993
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::forwardCallTo(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), "factory")
```

I am in the DatabaseSeeder.php file and I think the issue is coming from this code:

```
public function run()
{
    \App\Models\User::factory(3)->create()->each(function($u) {
        $u->questions()
          ->saveMany(
            //   factory(App\Question::class, rand(1,5))->make()
            \App\Models\Question::factory(rand(1,5))->make()
          );
    });
}
```

I get something similar after running this command in tinker:

```
>>> \App\Models\Question::factory(3)->make();
```

Link to repo is [here](https://github.com/Bayurzx/qna)
Any pointer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in your model you need the trait 'HasFactory' before you can use it

Comment: thanks for replying I added it, I just updated the post to include the repo link

Comment: Uncomment the HasFactory in your Question model, after that it should work```class Question extends Model
{
    // use HasFactory;```

Comment: Thanks man, I got another error, but at least, I think it works now. Much appreciated! Jesse de Boer